# Does straight line have sort of side property?

Tags: geometry

Let $x+y+1=0$ be a straight line $l_1$.

Is $l_2: -x-y-1=0$ the same line as $l_1$?

If there is a point $(0,0)$, put it into the equation of $l_1$, I have $0+0+1>0$. Let's say the point is on side $\alpha$ of $l_1$.

If I put point $(0,0)$ to equation of $l_2$, I have 0-0-1<0. Let's say the point is on side $\beta$ of $l_2$.

What do we know about $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

In general, does line have sort of side property?

Besides, can anyone show me if or how your prove holds in a $N$-dimensional space with a hyperplane $\vec{w}^T\vec{x}+b=0$ and a point.

Please show definitions, theorems, and references if possible. Thanks.

Comment: To answer the first question: yes, they are the same line, because a point $(x,y)$ satisfies $x+y+1=0$ iff $-x-y-1=0$. I'm not sure about the second part, since I don't know how exactly you define "side", but if you define it as one of the halfplanes bounded by the line, then we have $\alpha=\beta$.

Comment: @Wojowu Yes, I have gut feeling that $\alpha=\beta$, but want to see formal prove, or any properties/theorems about this.

Comment: Hint: consider the geometric meaning of the expression $x+y$, which can be written as the dot product $(x,y)\cdot(1,1)$ in terms of the line and a normal vector to it.

Answer (score 1):

All implicit curves have a "side property".

Let $f(x,y)=0$ be the implicit equation of a curve, where $f$ is a continuous function. The points that fulfill the equation are such that $f$ is zero. Then by continuity, you cannot move a point in the plane so that the sign of $f$ changes *without crossing the curve*. Hence the curve divides the plane in two regions* of opposite signs.

E.g.

$$f(x,y):=x^2+y^2-3=0$$ defines a circle, and $f$ is negative in the disk and positive outside.

*For non simply-connected curves, there will be more than two regions.

This immediately generalizes to higher dimensions.

Comment: Though it's good, can you give references? What's the name of the property you are talking about?

Comment: @Gqqnbig https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem